# How to cross-reference name of subfigures

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, subcaption, cleveref

I have a document where I use figures and subfigures (provided by the package `subcaption`). When I cross-reference subfigures using `\Cref{subfigure-label}` I get the right cross-reference, e.g., "Figure 1a", but when I try to get only its name, i.e., "figure", by means of `\nameCref{subfigure-label}` or `\lcnamecref{subfigure-label}` I get only question marks.

How could I get the names of the cross-referenced subfigures, namely, "figure" or, if possible, "subfigure" instead of the question marks?.

[image]

Here a MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
        %First landscape as subfigure
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{landscape.jpeg}
            \caption{first landscape}\label{fig:landscape-1}
        \end{subfigure}\hspace{0.2\textwidth}
        %Second landscape as subfigure
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{landscape.jpeg}
            \caption{second landscape}\label{fig:landscape-2}
        \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Two landscapes}\label{fig:landscapes}
    \end{figure}

    %Text cross-referencing the figures and subfigures
    Above there is a \lcnamecref{fig:landscapes}, its name is \Cref{fig:landscapes}.\\
    \Cref{fig:landscape-1} is a beautiful landscape, and so in \Cref{fig:landscape-2}.
    The first landscape is a \lcnamecref{fig:landscape-1} 
    and the second is a \nameCref{fig:landscape-2} too. 

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use `\crefname{subfigure}{figure}{figures}
\Crefname{subfigure}{Figure}{Figures}` before `\begin{document}` and load `cleveref` *after* `subcaption`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to inform `cleveref` about the meaning of `subfigure` counter reference information. This is not done (yet) in `cleveref`, so `\crefname{subfigure}{figure}{figures}` and `\Crefname{subfigure}{Figure}{Figures}` is needed, otherwise `??` is displayed.

Change `figure` to `subfigure` etc. if needed/desired.

`cleveref` should also loaded at last package, even after `hyperref`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefname{subfigure}{figure}{figures}
\Crefname{subfigure}{Figure}{Figures}
\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
        %First landscape as subfigure
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{landscape.jpeg}
            \caption{first landscape}\label{fig:landscape-1}
        \end{subfigure}\hspace{0.2\textwidth}
        %Second landscape as subfigure
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{landscape.jpeg}
            \caption{second landscape}\label{fig:landscape-2}
        \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Two landscapes}\label{fig:landscapes}
    \end{figure}

    %Text cross-referencing the figures and subfigures
    Above there is a \lcnamecref{fig:landscapes}, its name is \Cref{fig:landscapes}.\\
    \Cref{fig:landscape-1} is a beautiful landscape, and so in \Cref{fig:landscape-2}.
    The first landscape is a \lcnamecref{fig:landscape-1} 
    and the second is a \nameCref{fig:landscape-2} too. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am really glad and thankful for an easy and perfectly correct answer in some minutes time. But It feels like I am unskilled in LaTeX; I, myself, should have found this answer. ;)

Comment: very good for your excellent work +1.